# How to toggle graph in streamlit?

Tags: dashboard, streamlit

I have two kind of chart to display based on user selection that can be changed by user dynamically. I have two buttons female and male. If female button is clicked female data plot should be shown in the left column. And if the user clicks male button again the male data plot should be shown in the same place replacing previous plot. The plots are done in plotly. How to  achieve this? ~Quite new to streamlit so please ignore mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any code, the code below should give you the idea of how to work around it. But if this didn't solve your problem, provide some code, I am pretty sure once your question is clear someone can offer a better solution.

```py
left_col, right_col = st.columns(2)
with left_col:
    female_button = st.button("Female graph")
    male_button = st.button("Male graph")
    if female_button:
        st.write(female_plot)
    elif male_button:
        st.write(male_plot)
```